# Spring Boot Connect to H2 Database

Tags: java, spring-boot

I was creating an application with Spring Boot and I have this problem.
When I send JSON with Postman with the data...

[image]

...it returns this:

[image]

In H2 the values are inserted as null.

[image]

Spring starter code.

Springboothdbh2Application.java

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
    
@SpringBootApplication
public class Springboothdbh2Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Springboothdbh2Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Customer.java

```java
package com.example.demo.entity;
    
import java.util.Date;
    
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
    
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;
    
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
    
@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_customer")
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
public class Customer {
    
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
      private Long id;
    
      private String name;
    
      private Long age;
    
      private String location;
    
       @CreationTimestamp
       @Column(name="created_at", nullable=false, updatable=false)
      private Date createdAt;
    
       @UpdateTimestamp
       @Column(name="updated_at")
      private Date updatedAt;
    
}
```

CustomerController.java

```java
    package com.example.demo.controller;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Optional;
    
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
    import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
    
    import com.example.demo.entity.Customer;
    import com.example.demo.repository.ICustomerRepo;
    
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api")
    public class CustomerController {
        
        @Autowired
        ICustomerRepo customerRepo;
        
        @GetMapping("/customers")
        public ResponseEntity<List<Customer>> getAllCustomers() {
        try {
            List<Customer> list = customerRepo.findAll();
            
            if (list.isEmpty() || list.size() == 0) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }
            
            return new ResponseEntity<>(list, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/customers/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> getCustomer(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<Customer> customer = customerRepo.findById(id);
        
        if (customer.isPresent()) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(customer.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/customers")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> saveCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(customerRepo.save(customer), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/customers")
    public ResponseEntity<Customer> updateCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(customerRepo.save(customer), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/customers/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteCustomer(@PathVariable Long id) {
        try {
            Optional<Customer> customer = customerRepo.findById(id);
            if (customer.isPresent()) {
                customerRepo.delete(customer.get());
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

ICustumerRepo.java

```java
package com.example.demo.repository;
    
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
    
import com.example.demo.entity.Customer;
    
public interface ICustomerRepo extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {
    
}
```

This is my Spring Boot application properties file:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:crm
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
 
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Comment: Spring handles configuration of most in memory databases really well, so you shouldn't need any configuration for a H2 database.

Comment: How to make this code work?

Comment: What does the application log when you make the post request?

Comment: Check whether the customer object in request body does not contain null

Comment: Annotate ICustomerRepo Interface with @Repository annotation

Comment: now return this, `{
    "timestamp": "2022-08-13T03:08:26.354+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/api/customers"
}`

Comment: I wouldn't use `try catch` in every endpoint (it creates clutter), rather throw a custom exception and annotate the exception with something like this: `@ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, reason = "Actor Not Found")` or use an `ExceptionHandler`.

Answer (score 1):

to fix the code add setter to getters ta so in Customer.java

```
package com.example.demo.entity;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_customer")
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
public class Customer {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    private String name;
    
private Long age;

private String location;

@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name="created_at", nullable=false, updatable=false)
private Date createdAt;

@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name="updated_at")
private Date updatedAt;

public Long getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Long age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: Good job. However, I would only use the `@Setter ` notation on the fields that need it, not the whole class. So: name, age, location. That way you do not allow changing thing that should not need to be changed.

Comment: could you do an example?

Comment: Just remove the `@Setter` on Customer and put them on the members, like this: `@Setter private Long age;` You are also using both Lombok annotations and are providing you own implementation. The `@Getter` and `@Setter` annotations from Lombok generate these functions for you, to minimize clutter from boilerplate in your class. So either remove the annoations, or remove the get/set functions and add Lombok to your dependencies

Comment: I can't provide this in an answer, since it isn't really an answer to your question. You can take a look at [this entity](https://github.com/H3AR7B3A7/SpringBootTDD/blob/master/src/main/java/be/dog/d/steven/springboottdd1/Car.java) in one of my recent repos on github that utilizes Lombok annotations. You can find information on Lombok [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/).